# ImageView not showing in ListView Android 4.0

Tags: android, listview, url, imageview

I am trying to display the profile image from a twitter list.  I have a listview being used with Async task.  My ImageView is being done dynamically in a drawable from the URL.  It seems to work fine on the 2.3.3, but the image does not show on 4.0.  I ImageView has to work on 4.0.  I'm puzzled.
Here is from my adapter:

```
    Tweet o = tweets.get(position);
               Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromUrl.LoadImageFromWebOperations(o.profile_image_url);
               image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

The method that converts to URL to drawable is this:

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        try {
            Log.i("URL", url);
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And my xml layout for my list items (tweets)is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dip" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
     android:layout_width="48dip"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_margin="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="Profile Image"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<!-- Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/profile_image"
    android:paddingBottom="1dip"
    android:textColor="#0598DD"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- Screen name -->   
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/screen_name"
    android:layout_below="@id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
    android:paddingBottom="1dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

 <!-- Tweet -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:paddingBottom="1dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- date -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_stamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/text"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:textColor="#0598DD"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody responded.  I fixed this by using the UrlImageViewHelper:

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image, o.profile_image_url);
```